# No mostrar línea adicional en select de Laravel Collective

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

Uso Laravel Collective para mostrar varios select, pero hay uno que me muestra una línea y un símbolo que no debería estar allí:

Para este código:

```
{!! Form::select('business_id[]', ['' => 'Empresa', $business], null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}
```

Muestra la linea gris y el símbolo (No debería estar allí)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sí lo escribo, no muestra la línea pero no tengo tengo el encabezado (título) "Empresa":

```
{!! Form::select('business_id[]', $business, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}
```

Comment: "Empresa" quieres que sea una opción o sólo el placeholder?

Comment: Solo el placeholder

Comment: Entonces, pasalo como atributo junto a `class` y `required`. Algo así `{!! Form::select('business_id[]', $business, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Empresa', 'required']) !!}`

Comment: Gracias, funcionó perfectamente

Comment: Escríbela como respuesta para seleccionarla!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el cuarto argumento del método `select()` puedes pasarle los atributos html a la etiqueta `<select>`.

[Generating a Drop-Down List With an Empty Placeholder](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.x/html#drop-down-lists).

`'placeholder' => 'Empresa',` creará un elemento `<option>` sin valor como la primera opción de su menú desplegable.

```
{!! Form::select(
    'business_id[]', 
    $business, 
    null, 
   [
       'class' => 'form-control', 
       'placeholder' => 'Empresa', 
       'required'
   ]
) !!}
```